# Save Streaming dataframe in MongoDB using Spark Scala

Tags: mongodb, eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I'm using Kakfa and Spark, my ouput(df1) is a streaming Dataframe I would like to save it into MongoDB. Any suggestions? 
Many thanks!

```
  val df= lines.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String)]

  .select(from_json($"value", DFschema).as("data"))
  .select("data.*")
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate", "false")
  .start()
 .awaitTermination()

  df1 = df.filter($"COLUMN".isin(listA: _*))

  // save df1 into MongoDB
   //MongoSpark.save()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some methods to interact with mongodb with spark

```
val mongodb_input_uri = "mongodb://" + interface + ":" + port + "/" + database + "." + collection
    val mongodb_output_uri = "mongodb://" + interface + ":" + port + "/" + database + "." + collection

    val sparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongodb_input_uri)
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", mongodb_output_uri)
.getOrCreate()


def writeData(sparkSession: SparkSession, dataframe : DataFrame)= {
    dataframe.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").save()
  }

  def readData(sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val data = sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()

    data

}
```

Source : [github_source_code](https://github.com/PierreKieffer/mongodb-spark-connector/tree/master/src/main/scala)